# asp.net not logging user out

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

Banging my head against a brick wall again. I'm trying to get my ASP.NET Web Forms web app to log out but it's refusing to do so. I'm using Forms Authentication. The problem seems to be that the browser (ALL of the ones I've tried) are maintaining a cache of the pages after logging in but not clearing that cache on logout.

When I click the logout link on the main page, it transfers me successfully to the login page but I can just type in the page's URL or press back on the browser and it loads up the page again without needing to log in.

I've spent the past couple of hours scouring StackOverflow and elsewhere for a solution but so far nothing has worked.

My root web.config has this:

```
<authentication mode ="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

This is the web.config in my Account folder.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="Manage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

This is my code for logging out. As you can see, I've implemented ***everything*** I've found online. This is in my master page's cs file.

```
    public void Logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearSession();

        // Clear authentication cookie
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        // Clear session cookie
        SessionStateSection sessionStateSection = (SessionStateSection)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
        HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie(sessionStateSection.CookieName, "");
        cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);

        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }

    protected void ClearSession()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Clear();
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1d);
        Response.Expires = -1500;
        Response.CacheControl = "no-Cache";
    }
```

In my Page_Init (again, master page cs file), I have this:

```
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");

        // The code below helps to protect against XSRF attacks
        var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey];
        Guid requestCookieGuidValue;
        if (requestCookie != null && Guid.TryParse(requestCookie.Value, out requestCookieGuidValue))
        {
            // Use the Anti-XSRF token from the cookie
            _antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value;
            Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;
        }
        else
        {
            // Generate a new Anti-XSRF token and save to the cookie
            _antiXsrfTokenValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;

            var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Value = _antiXsrfTokenValue
            };
            if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL && Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                responseCookie.Secure = true;
            }
            Response.Cookies.Set(responseCookie);
        }

        Page.PreLoad += master_Page_PreLoad;
    }
```

And finally in my master page header, I have these meta tags.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="proxy-revalidate" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As is usually the case, I figure out the problem after doing some more searching and hitting a lightbulb moment - right after requesting help.

In case someone else is having problems, here's the solution that worked for me.

Although it's set up to use Forms Authentication, when I looked back at the default asp.net login page and the associated cs page I realised it was using the Identity.Owin namespace for logging in.

So in my logout, I replaced the first block of code above with:

```
    public void Logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearSession();

        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }

    protected void ClearSession()
    {
        Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        Session.Abandon();
    }
```